# move jQuery code to a function

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('.show-additional-link').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    $(this).hide();
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="native_language">Select</label>
    <select name="native_language" id="native_language">
      <option value="">Any</option>
      <option value="1">English</option>
    </select>

    <a class="show-additional-link" href="#">Select Additional Languages</a>
</div>

<div id="additional-languages" style="display: none;">      
    <div class="row">
        <!-- additional language checkboxes -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to move the contents of my jQuery code (within the 'click' function) in to a separate function, as I will need to call it again on page load (after the form is submitted, so that the DIV is shown again automatically).

I'm having trouble with this - can anyone help?

Comment: @Pekka Probably something to do with `this`.

Comment: Well I've tried doing it to the best of my ability but I'm struggling. I'm not sure what values to pass in to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$('.show-additional-link').click(function() {return showAdditional(this);});

function showAdditional(e) {
    $(e).parent().next().slideDown();
    $(e).hide();
    return false;
}
```

and on page load something like `showAdditional($('#linkyouwantclicked'))`

Comment: OK the normal click works fine for this, but it does not work for page load. Thinking about it, I think the A tag needs an ID - so that way we can directly refer to that particular A tag on page load. How can the code be modified to refer to the ID tag instead?

Comment: you would simply need to assign each A tag a unique id, then set the onload passing it the id

Comment: Cheers mate, all sorted. will carry out further testing and if all OK will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can manually trigger events. This should keep the right context for the handlers without any extra hassles.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // when the document has loaded
    $('.show-additional-link')
        .click(function () {    // set up the handler
            // your code here
        })
        .click()                // trigger the handler
    ;
});
```

Comment: Hey I didn't know about that trick - that's brilliant! It works but there is one issue - I only want this trigger event to happen IF a checkbox in the DIV was checked (i.e. if the checkbox variable exists in the $_GET array). Can we run this trigger manually?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.show-additional-link').each(function() {makeClickable($(this));}));


function makeClickable(el) { 
    el.click(function(){
        el.parent().next().slideDown();
        el.hide();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: But if I called makeClickable(el) on page load it wouldn't work though would it, because it's looking for a 'click' action.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showAdditional() {
    $('.show-additional-link').parent().next().slideDown();
    $('.show-additional-link').hide();
  }
</script>
```

and change your show-additional-link href to `"javascript:showAdditional()"` ?